# How to check if values of a DateType column are within a range of specified dates?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

So, I'm using Amazon Deequ in Spark, and I have a dataframe `df` with a column `publish_date` which is of type `DateType`. I simply want to check the following:

```
publish_date <= current_date(minus)x AND publish_date >= current_date(minus)y
```

where `x` and `y` are integers.

I'm not sure what check to put here:

```
val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
      .onData(df)
      .addCheck(
        Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check")
          //function to check this
      )
      .run()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this Spark SQL expression :

```sql
publish_date <= date_sub(current_date(), x) AND publish_date >= date_sub(current_date(), y)
```

With Check's [satisfies](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/fc3b30715570e7e3f558fb7bcc3abe4cff83914d/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check.scala#L667) method:

```
val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
      .onData(df)
      .addCheck(
        Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check")
          .satisfies(
            s"publish_date <= date_sub(current_date(), $x) AND publish_date >= date_sub(current_date(), $y)",
            "check constraint name/description"
        )
      )
      .run()
}
```

Or using `between`:

```sql
publish_date between date_sub(current_date(), y) and date_sub(current_date(), x)
```